# Всё верно написано, но функция не вызывается в js?

Tags: php, javascript, css, ajax

Есть простая проверка на js

```
function validateForm() {
  var x = document.forms["myForm"]["options"].value;
  if (x == null || x == "") {
    swal({
      title: "Errors!",
      text: "Quiz 1 !",
      imageUrl: "images/thumbs-up.jpg"
    });
    return false;
  }
  var y = document.forms["myForm"]["optionsx"].value;
  if (y == null || y == "") {
    swal({
      title: "Sweet!",
      text: "Quiz 2 !",
      imageUrl: "images/thumbs-up.jpg"
    });

    function isEmail() {
      swal({
          title: "Text",
          text: "Enter you name  !",
          type: "input",
          showCancelButton: true,
          closeOnConfirm: false,
          animation: "slide-from-top",
          inputPlaceholder: "Ex. Alexandra"
        },
        function(inputValue) {
          if (inputValue === false) return false;
          if (inputValue === "") {
            swal.showInputError("No name !");
            return false
          }
          swal("Brav!", inputValue + ", go to OK button !", "success");
        });

      isEmail();
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

вот и html код

```
<h3>Quiz1</h3>
<form method=" POST" name="myForm" onsubmit="return validateForm()" action="load.php">
  <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
      <input name="options" id="option1" type="radio">Yes !
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
      <input name="options" id="option2" type="radio">No !
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary ">
      <input name="options" id="option3" type="radio">50 and 50
    </label>
  </div>

  <h3>Quiz2</h3>

  <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
      <input name="optionsx" id="option4" type="radio">No !
      </ label>
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input name="optionsx" id="option5" type="radio">Yes !
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-primary ">
        <input name="optionsx" id="option6" type="radio">50 and 50
      </label>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Find" onclick="validateForm()" />
</form>
```

перенаправляет на файл load.php , проверка не срабатывает !
Почему ?
И как передать кроме как ajax-ом значения переменой inputValue который человек водит если выбрал ответы на всё вопросы и нажал кнопку срабатывает функ. isEmail () ?
Да прибудет с вами сила !

Comment: какая функция не вызывается? почему думаешь что не вызывается? есть ли ошибки в консоли?

Comment: обратите внимание, что _validateForm_ всегда вызывается **дважды**

Answer (score 1):

1. Проверьте, чтобы не было логических js-ошибок. Например, сейчас функция `isEmail` вызывается внутри самой себя. Функцию `swal` вы не привели.
2. Объявление функции `isEmail` лучше перенести наружу из `validateForm`. Собственно, из-за этого форма и отправляется (почему то).
3. Главное, return false должен быть всегда, а не только в определённых случаях. Сейчас последний `return false;` у вас внутри isEmail, а не в `validateForm`.

Comment: форма отправляется, потому что в строке `onsubmit="return validateForm()" функция в большинстве случаев не возвращает `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте в конец кода

```
window.validateForm = validateForm;
```

Comment: Судя по коду, область видимости и так глобальная, зачем переприсваивать?